Export-Excel not working in Azure Functions
I am importing a csv file in Azure Functions (Powershell) and I would like to export it as an excel file. I decided to use the Export-Excel module. Unfortunately, when I add it to my requirements:
@{
    Az = '2.*'
    SqlServer = '21.1.18147'
    ImportExcel = '7.8.6'
}

I am getting the following error:
Result: Failure Exception: Failed to install function app dependencies. Error: 'The script file 'requirements.psd1' has parsing errors: Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.

Then I downloaded the whole module and uploaded it to my "Modules" folder (on KUDU). When I tried then to import the module, I received again an error:
ERROR: The specified module 'Export-Excel' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

In the end I simply took the whole function's code (found here: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/1.90/Content/Export-Excel.ps1) and included it straight into my code - then when I tried to invoke it, I got the following error:
ERROR: Unable to find type [OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle].

Has anyone ever managed to use this module on Azure Functions? Is it even possible?

I have reproduced in my environment and below are my expected results:
requirements.psd1:
@{
    'Az' = '11.*'
    'ImportExcel' = '7.8.4'
}

run.ps1:
using namespace System.Net

param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)
Install-Module -Name ImportExcel -Force
Import-Module -Name ImportExcel -Force

$csvData = @"
Name, Age, City
Rithwik, 23, Hyd
Bojja, 24, Sec
Chotu, 24, Island
"@

$testobj = ConvertFrom-Csv -InputObject $csvData
$tempExcelFile = New-TemporaryFile
$testobj | Export-Excel -Path $tempExcelFile.FullName -AutoSize -NoHeader -WorksheetName "Data"
$path=$tempExcelFile.FullName
Write-Output "Temporary file created at: $path"

Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = $testobj
})

host.json:
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "managedDependency": {
    "Enabled": true
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  },
      "functionTimeout": "00:10:00"
}

Output:


The "Install-Module" line did the trick! I thought I didn't have to do it and that adding the module to the requirements would be sufficient. Thanks a lot!
